# Run Hello World on phone from Android Studio Hangs

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-install-apk

I am truing to run the basic "Hello World" app from Android Studio. I can run it on a virtual device successfully. However, running the apps on my own device (Samsung S3 GT-I9300 android version 4.3) doesn't work.

The execution is stopped after displaying:

---

Waiting for device.

Target device: samsung-gt_i9300-3230569a7027a07f

Uploading file

```
local path: C:\Users\Sasha\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.sasha.myfirstapp
```

---

Manual installation of the .apk through adb is non-responsive as-well.

1. I've added in AndroidManifest.xml the tag: android:debuggable="true".
2. The device is recognized by adb and Android Studio.
3. I've changed the minSdkVersion to 17 in defaultConfig in build.gradle.

Comment: logcat output may help…

Comment: The logcat just stops when I try to run from Android studio

Comment: Problem was solved by changing USB cable and USB port

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Invalidate Caches / Restart`. It solved the problem for me.

If the app is deployed properly on a different device but not on this one, then it is most likely a problem with your device's debug settings. If the device is safely out of its warranty period, I would recommend rooting the device to gain access to many more features as a developer.

Cheers!!  :)